# Gmail App: Find threads which have a calendar entry

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Some messages have calendar entries at the top of them like this: [image]

In GScript, is there any way to find messages which have these calendar entries? If so, how does one extract the information from it?

**Update**

I took a lucky shot and found that it's classed as an attachment (of type `ics`), but there still remains the issue of extracting the data from this file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getIcs(){
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var thread, messages, message, attachments, attachment;
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
    messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++){
      message = messages[j];
      attachments = message.getAttachments();
      for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++){
        attachment = attachments[k];        
        if(attachment){
          if (attachment.getContentType() == "application/ics"){
            Logger.log("found ics");//continue;
            result.push(message);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

This method will view every thread, every message in it and every attachment in each message, and returns a list of the [message objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message) that have an attachment of type `application/ics`.

**UPDATE**

In addition to my previous code, the following function will return an array of event objects based on the attachments found in the other method:

```
function getSutff(){
  var msgs = getIcs();
  var ics;
  var position;
  var eventId;
  var event = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++){
    ics = msgs[i].getAttachments()[0].getDataAsString();
    position = (ics.search("UID:")) + 4;
    eventId = ics.substr(position,26);
    event.push(CalendarApp.getEventById(eventId));
  }
  Logger.log(event)
  return event;
}
```

Comment: Thank you...I've already reached that stage and I'm now trying to actually read the information from the ics file. Maybe this should be a separate question. I found https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/116730/226921 which may work but I'm not sure how I can pass the file from the attachment into this method. I have zero rep on the webapps section so can't comment on that question.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do with the .ics file? Create the event?

Comment: For my current purpose I just want to be able to extract time and date information from it. For the future it would be useful to know how to get other properties from it too.

Comment: I updated my answer to include how to find the data on the event. From that event object you can get all the properties you want and even edit them if you have permissions.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't even realise that all of the data was there in the string. Thank you!